# Alpine variants of PHP and Apache/httpd in Docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, alpine-linux

I am experimenting with Docker and want to move from a local MAMP stack to Docker. Of course I stumbled upon the official `php:7.0` image but I want to use Apache as well so it seems as if `php:7.0-apache` is the way to go. However I saw that there is an image called `php:7.0-alpine` which is much slimmer while there are two versions for Apache as well namely `httpd:2.4` and `httpd:2.4-alpine`.

Is there any suggested combination to use both Apache and PHP (either separated or combined) while still having small image sizes? Furthermore I would like to know where I can review the available modules in the images since I want to use MariaDB and mod_rewrite as well which could possibly have more dependencies which have been omitted to keep the size small.

---

#### Information on implementing the desired infrastructure with nginx

I came across [this very detailed and awesome tutorial](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/docker-for-php-developers) on how to split up nginx and PHP as well as MySQL into different containers but attach PHP to nginx using FCGI. This implies that I can use all the different alpine-based images of the tools and link them using FCGI. Unfortunately I have never heard of or worked with FCGI but I guess some more research will yield information on how to implement this infrastructure using Apache.

Comment: You may want to checkout https://github.com/8ctopus/apache-php-fpm-alpine

Comment: Super useful blog post about this for anyone else who finds this question:  https://www.cloudreach.com/en/technical-blog/containerize-this-how-to-use-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Running Apache/NGINX and PHP with FCGI

If you want to run Apache and PHP in separate containers, you'll need to use a PHP-FPM container (like for example, using the `php:7-fpm` or `php:7-fpm-alpine` image) and then use FCGI to connect the two. By default, the [official PHP-FPM images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) expose the TCP port 9000 for this, which should be sufficient for most cases.

For PHP-FPM, the [official PHP image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) should do fine (regarding size, the `7.0.14-fpm-alpine` tag is only 31M in size). Regarding Apache, I've come to like the [`webdevops/apache` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/apache/) (I'm not affiliated in any way). It also comes with an Alpine-based version that is only 38M in size and works well together with PHP-FPM.

Here's how you start separate PHP-FPM and Apache containers, linked together using FCGI:

```
$ docker run -d \
    -v /path/to/data:/var/www/html \
    --name fpm \
    php:fpm-7.0.14-alpine
$ docker run -d \
    -v /path/to/data:/var/www/html \
    --name apache \
    --link fpm \
    -e WEB_PHP_SOCKET=fpm:9000 \
    -e WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html \
    webdevops/apache:alpine-3
```

For using Nginx instead, simply substitute the `webdevops/apache` image with `webdevops/nginx`.

#### Adding custom extensions

Since you've also asked about adding additional PHP extensions to your image: this is covered in the official PHP image's documentation. You can add custom PHP extensions to the PHP base image by running `docker-php-ext-install` in a custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.14-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

This allows you to build your custom image based on one of the PHP-FPM base images, adding all extensions that you require in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: If you're interested to know more about using the official Apache image please refer to my own answer. Yours has helped me out A LOT to get started in the first place :)

Answer (score 13):

#### Running official Apache and PHP with FCGI

In addition to [helmbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995300/helmbert)s proposed solution which worked for me I was fiddling around with the official `httpd:2.4-alpine` image. I want to add some more information and caveats I stumbled upon while working on this.

- The Apache configuration was slightly more difficult since it is a lighter version with no usual vhost data structure, no `a2en*` and no `a2dis*` scripts.
- There is no generic folder structure in `/etc/apache2`. Everything is in `/usr/local/apache2` and you have your global `httpd.conf` in `/usr/local/apache2/conf/`. In this file you have to uncomment the module lines manually to load them as well as further configuration files like `httpd-vhosts.conf` which is stored in `/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/`.
- I used the `httpd-vhosts.conf` to setup the basic options for my testing:

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/main-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/main-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

- For the FCGI server I had to uncomment the following two lines:

---

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
```

---

- Everytime to change something in the configuration you have to `./bin/apachectl restart` as usual assuming you are in `/usr/local/apache2`.
- Since I use `nano` I had to install it manually using `apk --no-cache add nano`. This can be done in an interactive session or globally using a `Dockerfile` to fork the base image.
- I had an error when opening `nano` - in my case I had to `export TERM=xterm` in an interactive shell or `ENV TERM xterm` in the `Dockerfile`.
- It turned out that `php-fpm` has to have access to the very same files - this is something I didn't actually notice in the proposed solution at first. This means as well that I had the source files mounted at two different paths (`/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` in the `httpd` image and `/var/www/html` in the `php-fpm` image) and had to forward calls properly. I used the following line in the `httpd.conf`.

---

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "fcgi://fpm:9000/var/www/html/$1"
```

---

- The `fpm` name in the FCGI link is the name of my container that is linked to `httpd` using `--link fpm` and automatically added to the `/etc/hosts`.
- So far I managed to achieve want I want by interactively doing all these changes. I am going to add all the changes to my `Dockerfile` using either `COPY` commands or applying basic `sed` calls.
- I know there is the possibility to use unix sockets via the command `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock|fcgi://fpm/"` but I don't know if that is useful or not.

Comment: Hi, I ve tried to add ProxyPassMatch setting on my configuration, but still didn't manage to make it work properly. See here for ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079174/docker-apache-php-fpm-getting-blank-page-on-browser